# Python how to do ludecomposition and inverse

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do a matrix operation. the original logic we have in java is like this:

```
inverseMatrix = LUDecomposition(matrix).getSolver().getInverse()
```

The LUDecomposition used here is: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/LUDecomposition.html#getSolver()

I'm finding a way to implement this in python, does anyone know what would be a good way to do so?

Sorry I'm not quite familiar with matrix operations...Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look into the `scipy` package, and specifically `scipy.linalg.lu`.

Comment: there also is `scipy.linalg.inv` (short for inverse) see  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.inv.html

Comment: It's interesting that this isn't a question about Python or a Python library. Rather, it's a question about *finding* a Python library that can perform LU Decomposition, which can be easily solved by doing a Google search.